# Waitlist Plugin Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the Waitlist plugin on my website, and it works perfectly when the product is variable, but when the product is simple it has the "Out of stock" tag, the warning and the button above my header.

My theme is: Xstore
My website is: https://drop.com.br/

For product variable
[Product Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgSUU.png)

For Simple Product
[Product Simple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYONu.png)

I tried to solve the problem using css, but it didn't work.
The theme doesn't have anything specific talking about a stock list, just an out-of-stock warning after the product description.

This is a Code to plugin Waitlist:

```
    if( $isVariation ) {
            $is_oos = $this->productStock_quantity( $_product->get_parent_id(), $_product->get_id(), false ) ? false : true;
            $bo = $_product->get_backorders();
            if( $is_oos && ( !$based_on_quantity || !in_array( $bo, array( 'yes', 'notify' ) ) || $subscibe_backorders_setting ) ) {
                $display_variationOutOfStock = true;
            }
        } else {
            $is_oos = $this->productStock_quantity( $_product->get_id(), 0, false ) ? false : true;
            $bo = $_product->get_backorders();
            if( $is_oos && ( !$based_on_quantity || !in_array( $bo, array( 'yes', 'notify' ) ) || $subscibe_backorders_setting ) ) {
                $display_outOfStock = true;
            }
        }

        $display_msg = $availability['availability'];
        $display_classes = " stock in-msg " . $availability['class'] . " ";
        $notify_msg = "";

        $verified_code = get_option('woowaitlist_product_verified_code') ? trim(get_option('woowaitlist_product_verified_code')) : '';

        $is_active_license = $verified_code == '' ? 0 : 1;

        $form_fields = '';

        if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $form_fields .= '<button id="wew-submit-email-to-notify" class="add_to_cart_button logged button">' . $this->get_subscribe_button_str() . '</button>';
        } else {
            $form_fields .= '<input type="text" name="wew-email-to-notify" class="wew-email-to-notify" placeholder="' . $this->get_email_placeholder_str() . '" />';
            $tStr = $this->get_subscribe_button_str() != '' ? $this->get_subscribe_button_str() : __( "Subscribe", 'woocommerce-waitlist' );
            $form_fields .= '<button id="wew-submit-email-to-notify" class="add_to_cart_button button">' . $tStr . '</button>';
        }
        $form_fields .= '<img class="wew-spinner" src="' . admin_url( 'images/spinner.gif' ) . '" />';

        if( !$isVariation && ( ( $display_outOfStock && $this->get_hc() == 0 ) || ( $display_outOfStock && $this->get_hc() > 0 && $isGrouped ) ) ) {

            if( $this->get_hc() == 0 || ( $this->get_hc() > 0 && $isGrouped ) ){

                if( $isGrouped ){

                    $oosType = "grouped";
                }
                else{

                    $oosType = "stock";
                }

                ?>

                <input type="hidden" class="wew-id-for-notify" value="<?php echo $_product->get_id(); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="wew-has-lic" id="wew-has-lic" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $is_active_license ); ?>" />

                <?php

                if( $this->get_hc() == 0 ){

                    if( $isGrouped ){ ?>

                        <input type="hidden" id="oos-parentid" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $_product->get_parent_id() ); ?>" /><?php
                    }

                    ?>
                    <input type="hidden" id="oos-type" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $oosType ); ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="wew-is-logged-in" id="wew-is-logged-in" value="<?php echo is_user_logged_in(); ?>" /><?php
                }

            }

            if( $is_active_license ) {

                if( in_array( $bo, array( 'yes', 'notify' ) ) ) {
                    $display_msg = $availability['availability'];
                    $display_classes = " stock in-msg " . $availability['class'] . " ";
                    echo '<p class="'.$display_classes.'">'.$display_msg.'</p>';
                } else {
                    $display_msg = get_option('wew-out-of-stock-str') ? get_option('wew-out-of-stock-str') : __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce-waitlist' );
                    $display_classes = " stock out-msg " . $availability['class'] . " ";
                    echo '<p class="'.$display_classes.'">'.$display_msg.'</p>';
                    $notify_msg = get_option('wew-out-of-stock-message') ? get_option('wew-out-of-stock-message') : __( 'Notify me when item is back in stock', 'woocommerce-waitlist' );
                    echo '<p class="oos-message">' . $notify_msg . '</p>';
                }

                $display_form = '<div class="wew-notification-action_wrapper">' . $form_fields . '</div>';

                echo $display_form;

            } else {

                echo '<p><strong>' . __( "WooWaitlist Activation Pending", 'woocommerce-waitlist' ) . '</strong></p>';
            }

            $this->set_hc( intval( $this->get_hc() ) + 1 );

            remove_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', array( $this, 'wew_check_product_availability' ) );

            return;

        } elseif( $isVariation && !$display_outOfStock ) {

            if( $this->get_hc() == 0 ){

                $oosType = "variation";

                ?>

                <input type="hidden" id="oos-type" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $oosType ); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" class="wew-id-for-notify" value="<?php echo $_product->get_parent_id(); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="wew-is-logged-in" id="wew-is-logged-in" value="<?php echo is_user_logged_in(); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="wew-has-lic" id="wew-has-lic" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $is_active_license ); ?>" /><?php
            }

            if( $display_variationOutOfStock ) {        // variation has NOT stock

                $cntv = 0;
                $variation_title = "";

                if( !$this->is_ajax() ) {
                    $form_fields = '';
                }

                if( in_array( $bo, array( 'yes', 'notify' ) ) ) {
                    $display_msg = trim( $availability['availability'] ) != '' ? $availability['availability'] : '';
                    $display_classes = $availability['class'];
                } else {
                    $display_msg = get_option('wew-out-of-stock-str') ? get_option('wew-out-of-stock-str') : __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce-waitlist' );

                    $display_classes = " stock out-msg " . $availability['class'] . " ";
                    $notify_msg = get_option('wew-variations-out-of-stock-message') ? get_option('wew-variations-out-of-stock-message') : __( 'Notify me when item variation is back in stock', 'woocommerce-waitlist' ) ;
                    $display_msg .= '<p class="oos-message">' . $notify_msg . '</p>';
                }

                $display_msg .= '<div class="wew-notification-action_wrapper variations">' . $form_fields . '</div>';

            }

            $this->set_hc( intval( $this->get_hc() ) + 1 );

        }

        $availability['availability'] = $display_msg ;
        $availability['class'] = $display_classes;

        $hidden_fields_output = ob_get_clean();
        if( !$this->is_ajax() ) {
            echo $hidden_fields_output;
        }

    }

    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', array( $this, 'wew_check_product_availability' ) );

    return $availability;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! You should contact the developer of the plugin.

Comment: Hello!
I've tried, but I wasn't successful...